# Как расширить статическое поле типа Array одним элементом?

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Мне потребовалось инициализировать в статическом классе некоторые последовательности байт (`A`) и просто байты (`B`, `C`, `D`). Также мне именно как `static byte[]` необходимы две последовательности. Первая - `DEFEND_A`. С ней проблем нет. **Вторая** - `DEFEND_B`. Она должна включать все элементы `DEFEND_A` **и** байт `D`. В этом то и проблема: я не могу придумать конструкцию для такой манипуляции такую, чтобы она заменяла комментарий `/* ?  ?  ? */` в следующем коде:

```
public static class SMTH_GLOBAL_CLASS {
    public static readonly byte[] A = new byte[] { 1, 2 };
    public static readonly byte   B = 3;
    public static readonly byte   C = 4;
    public static byte[] DEFEND_A = new byte[] { C, B, A[0] };

    public static readonly byte D = 5;
    public static byte[] DEFEND_B = /* ?  ?  ? */;
}
```

---

Единственное, до чего я дошел, так это следующий код:

```
byte[] DEFEND_B = new byte[DEFEND_A.Length + 1];
Array.Copy(DEFEND_A, DEFEND_B, DEFEND_A.Length);
DEFEND_B[DEFEND_A.Length] = D;
```

Его использование мне не подходит так как я бы хотел иметь доступ к `DEFEND_B` не только из метода, в который я вставляю этот код. Повторюсь, `DEFEND_B` должен быть `static byte[]` полем класса.

---

Я бы мог использовать конструкцию `new byte[] { C, B, A[0], D }` на месте `/* ?  ?  ? */`, но так я лишь усложню редактируемость последовательности `DEFEND_A`.

---

***Четко и ясно сформулирую вопрос:*** Какую конструкцию мне поставить на место комментария `/* ?  ?  ? */` такую, чтобы `DEFEND_B` включал все элементы `DEFEND_A` и байт `D`?

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить терминологию. В представленном коде нет _атрибутов_. A, B, C и т. д. - _поля_ (fields).

Comment: Я часто переключаюсь на разные языки программирования и из-за этого мне сложно соответствовать терминологическим особенностям каждого языка, который я понимаю. Я имел в виду «поле».

Comment: Боюсь показаться невежей, но чем обусловлено использование именно полей, а не свойств? Насколько я понимаю, при использовании свойств, эту задачу можно было бы решить проще и без дополнительного оверхеда при обращении к свойствам. Интересуюсь для своего, так сказать, развития.

Comment: `DEFEND_X` являются полями так как их мне нужно передавать по ссылке в некоторый метод. Свойства я не могу передать по ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static byte[] DEFEND_B = Create_DEFEND_B();
private static byte[] Create_DEFEND_B() {
  byte[] db = new byte[DEFEND_A.Length + 1];
  Array.Copy(DEFEND_A, db, DEFEND_A.Length);
  db[DEFEND_A.Length] = D;
  return db;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```
public static byte[] DEFEND_B => DEFEND_A?.Append(D).ToArray();
```

Но имейте ввиду, что конструкция выше на каждое обращение будет создавать новый массив в памяти.